# cannot use variable declared class in the function inside the same class. why ?

Tags: c#, .net, stackexchange-api

i have declared a variable in the class 'Main' with name 'context2'. But i cannot use the variable inside the function 'Main_Load'. what am i doing wrong ?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Soapi;
using Soapi.Domain;

namespace SO_Console_Client
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        const string apiKey = "*************";
        var context2 = new ApiContext(apiKey).Initialize(false);
        public Main(String GravatarURL, User user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Load(GravatarURL);  //Loads the Gravatar image from the url

            //set the reputation details
            lblRep.Text = String.Format("Reputation: {0}", user.Reputation);

            //Sets the badge details
            lblBadge.Text = String.Format("Badges: gold={0} silver={1} bronze={2}", user.BadgeCounts.Gold, user.BadgeCounts.Silver, user.BadgeCounts.Bronze);

            groupBox1.Text = user.DisplayName.ToString();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Soapi.Queries.QuestionsUnansweredQuery query = context2.Official.StackOverflow.Questions.Unanswered;
            foreach (Question q in query)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(q.Title.ToString());
                    //Console.WriteLine(q.Body.ToString());
                }
                catch (System.NullReferenceException ex)
                {

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't your example overly verbose?

Comment: You say you can't use it, what error do you see?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run this code?

Comment: Fields can't be defined as 'var', for one thing - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit typing doesn't work with fields; it only works with local variables.

I *think* this is what your real intention is:

```
ApiContext context2 = new ApiContext(apiKey);

public Main(String GravatarURL, User user)
{
   context2.Initialize(false);
   ...
}
```

In the highly unlikely case that `ApiContext` is some sort of fluent-interface for which `ApiContext.Initialize(bool)`returns a *different*`ApiContext`object, this should be what you want:

```
ApiContext context2 = new ApiContext(apiKey).Initialize(false);
```

although it would be much clearer if you did:

```
ApiContext context2;

public Main(String GravatarURL, User user)
{
   context2 = new ApiContext(apiKey).Initialize(false);
   ...
}
```

I really doubt that, though.

Answer (score 1):

This can't compile.  `var`-type variable declarations cannot be at the class level, only the method level.

Answer (score 1):

There are technical issues with allowing var to be used with fields. This is why a concrete type must be specified. Here is an explanation of the issues from Eric Lippert:

[Why no var on fields](https://ericlippert.com/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/)